pdfplumber does not read text on page breaks
I am extracting data from pdfplumber library tables.
I'm faced with the fact that I can't read the text in a cell divided into two pages. (attached photo)
This line is simply skipped when using var.extract_tables(), but when using var.extract_text() it is read.
I will be grateful if you help.
I thought for a long time about how to fix this, tried to play with the table_settings={} argument, but nothing good came of it.
